# How to center an bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal in table. I am calling modal as,

```
<td><a href="#basicModal" data-toggle="modal" >Assign</a></td>
```

and in modal code is as follow,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
        <label class="control-label">Subject:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender">
     <option value="">---------Select Subject--------</option> 
                    <option>Maths</option>
                    <option>Science</option>
                    <option>Social</option>

                </select>
        <label class="control-label">Teacher:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender">
                     <option value="">---------Select Subject--------</option> 
                    <option>Raghavendra M</option>
                    <option>Santosh</option>

                </select>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing here is I am not getting modal at the center of screen and here I am using small modal , it appear with in a some container kind of window. How can I solve this please help me.

Comment: So how are you getting the modal? Embedding the modal in the table probably causes the misplacement.

Comment: yes I am getting but its not properly appearing . .

Comment: How did you manage to make it not centered?

Comment: Do you mean it's not vertically centered? It seems to be centering horizontally: http://www.bootply.com/7mLNkCZhdc

Comment: yes I cant . Here I am not writing any css for it. Do I need to write?

Comment: Insert your modal div just before body tag or in starting of body tag.

Comment: @Baghoo In my case what is happening is . Model is appearing leftside and it is appearing within modal window outer modal has scroll bar at down inner modalis currect wht we are writing.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3? Your code will only work for Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @Baghoo What are the links you used

Comment: @Baghoo But actualy modal is appearing right, how will it be without bootstrap3!

Answer (score 1):

add `margin: 0 auto;` into your `.modal-sm`